# How do I tell 'may' which is used like 'do'?

Tags: word-usage

https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

> Be welcoming and patient, especially with those who **may** not know everything you do.

I thought this 'may' is [used to say that something is possible](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/may_1), like 'probably' or 'perhaps'.

But someone told me that 'may' has similar meaning as 'do' but it's softer than 'do'.

How do I tell the difference between those meaning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "someone" *may* (=possibly) have missed to point out the context in which "may" is used as "do", but that has a lot more to do with culture than language:

In English phrases like "You *may* want to sit down." are a way of avoiding a direct commands like "*Do* sit down." which *may* (=possibly) come across as impolite.

The straight translation / literal meaning of "may" remains the same ("Perhaps you want to sit down?") but the underlying message is a straight request or order.

So how to distinguish between those? It's a question of context. Who is the speaker? What is the topic? Is there a request or demand in a friendly packaging? Or is the speaker simply expressing a possibility or probability? In the former case you can remove all "may" and all verbs like "want" or "consider" to get the core message.

- > It may start to rain soon. -> possible, no request
- > You may want to finish this task first. -> order. Read: "Finish this task first."

---

There is also the *may* indicating permission ("May I have this seat?"), but that was not part of your question.

Comment: Your second example reads more like a suggestion than a command.

Comment: @User112638726 Exactly what I'm talking about: Taken at face value, yes. But if your boss makes this "suggestion" it's not really a suggestion.

Comment: Yes, but in most situations it is a suggestion, not a command, even in your example where a boss may say it, it is still a suggestion, but not following it may get you into trouble. I don't know if it is different where i am from (UK) but people almost never use it to issue commands.

Answer (score 1):

Your definition is accurate. Another way of writing that sentence would be as follows:

> Be welcoming and patient, especially as it is possible those you deal with do not know everything you do.

*May* expresses possibility. In a positive sense it states that "such and such **may be done**". In a conditional sense it states that "such and such can be **either true or false**."